# I would like to pass the attributes values in map for Jsoup Connect.data() method

Tags: java, xml, jsoup

The xml structure looks like the following.I would like to pass the id `name="hotelId"` `value="00000000003054D8"` and id `name="offerId" value="74"` to the **Jsoup's**  `Connect` class `data()` method.

```
<GetBookingIdsRequest token="f6ERmpwxbZ4ysUgCHB9mlSPcd9rf5DVB39C--yLbNSdG" sid="TVd8DY5OQi2vf82h" xmlns="http://www.travelfusion.com/xml/api/simple">
        <id name="hotelId" value="00000000003054D8"/>
        <id name="offerId" value="74"/>
</GetBookingIdsRequest>
```

How do I pass the same?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example how you get the values:

```
Document doc = ...

Elements request = doc.select("getbookingidsrequest");


for( Element element : request )
{
    final String hotelId = element.select("id[name=hotelId]").first().attr("value");
    final String offerId = element.select("id[name=offerId]").first().attr("value");

    System.out.println(hotelId);
    System.out.println(offerId);
}
```

**Output:**

```
00000000003054D8
74
```

If you have only a single `GetBookingIdsRequest`-tag you can use `first()` method instead of the `for`-loop:

```
Document doc = ...

Element request = doc.select("getbookingidsrequest").first();

final String hotelId = request.select("id[name=hotelId]").first().attr("value");
final String offerId = request.select("id[name=offerId]").first().attr("value");

System.out.println(hotelId);
System.out.println(offerId);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the replies...But my requirement is little different..I know how to get the values.But I would like to set the values in Jsoup.I am attaching my code..It's regarding how do I set the value.Following is the snippet of code.

Comment: <GetBookingIdsRequest token="WWfO43t3bqAIB5ESk5ODAYP_uRPHkkf0bsvRKoRK0_DG" sid="TMrSkFl3xonnjfuO" xmlns="http://www.travelfusion.com/xml/api/simple">
        <id name="hotelId" value="00000000003054D8"/>
        <id name="offerId" value="4"/>
</GetBookingIdsRequest>

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the below as part of the data map for the `Connection` object.

```
map.put("id[0].name", "hotelId");
map.put("id[0].value", hotel_Id);
map.put("id[1].name", "offerId");
map.put("id[1].value", offer_Id);
```